# Trying to use findOrFail() instead of get()

Tags: php, laravel

Instead of `get()` I would like to use `findOrFail` but it doesn't work that way.

So what is the best way to return a 404 response if the row doesn't exist?

```
$log = DB::table('dmlog')
->select(
    'dmlog.*',
    'membership.membership',
    'department.department',
    'category.category',
    'communication.communication',
    'room.room AS room',
    'room.category AS room_cat',
    'roommove.room AS roommove',
    'roommove.category AS roommove_cat'
)
->join('membership', 'membership.id', '=', 'id_membership')
->join('department', 'department.id', '=', 'id_department')
->join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'id_category')
->join('communication', 'communication.id', '=', 'id_communication')
->join('room', 'room.id', '=', 'id_room')
->join('room AS roommove', 'roommove.id', '=', 'id_roommove')
->where('dmlog.id', $id)->get(); // <----- HERE
return response()->json($log);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a line `abort_if($log->isEmpty(), 404);` before the return line to abort if `$log` is empty

Comment: You can use firstOrFail () to get an item

Answer (score 2):

findOrFail is an eloquent method, not a DB raw class method. You need to use eloquent.

You need to reference the model directly to use `findOrFail`

```
$model = App\YourModel::findOrFail($id);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Jeremy, thank you for your answer but as you can read, I do know that it doesn't work that way, I wrote it on my post. Now, I'm looking for a clean way/best practice to return a 404 response if the row doesn't exist.

Comment: All right, I think I know what you're about to say : "Why you don't use the model ?" it is because the request is quiet complex and the model doesn't allow me to write that kind of complex request. Example : I cannot use select() or table() on a model.